# How do I ask a question outside of meta?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am new and I don't see the button, I can only ask meta questions.

Comment: That's because you are visiting a separate site, Meta Stack Exchange. Go to the site where your question would be on-topic and sign in there.

Comment: thanks can I rate your comment up?

Comment: No need to rate it up; you cannot upvote answers until you have 15 points, anyway, and I used a comment because it isn't entirely clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: The bottom of this page contains a "blue" section of links to many of the StackExchange "subject matter" sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are on the meta site.

To ask a question on any other site just go there and ask.

Here is a list of all sites:

https://stackexchange.com/sites#name